# Strapi corporate starter custom component is not showing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

When following official documentation for creating custom components for strapi corporate starter in Next.js [Starter github page](https://github.com/strapi/starters-and-templates/tree/main/packages/starters/next-corporate#adding-sections) the created component is not shown on website.

I have created simple component called External link [image: External link component screenshot]

then I have added it to Page's contectSection [image]

Then I have created React component

```
import React from "react"
const ExternalLink = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="py-10 text-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
        <a href={data.address}>{data.title}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ExternalLink
```

and registered it in sectionComponents in sections.js

```
  ComponentSectionsExternalLink: ExternalLink,
```

Last step was to add it to page, so I have added it to homepage like so:
[image]

The problem is that the component is not retreived from strapi to frontend.
[image: Console log of all retreived homapage components]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make change in utils/api.js query

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).